# setTimeout position in code angular hack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plotly

```
    for(c=0; c < $scope.graphPlotsChunk.length; c++ ){
      if(c == 0){
           Plotly.newPlot(graphRender, [$scope.graphPlots2[c]], $scope.layout2);
      }else{   
           setTimeout(function() { 
              $scope.testCounter.push(_.clone(c));
              console.log($scope.testCounter);
              Plotly.addTraces(graphRender, $scope.graphPlots2[c]);
           },0);
      }
    }
```

call to Plotly addTraces throws an error because of unsyncroniced counter "c":
[image]

Without the timeout no error but traces wont reflect in the view until end of loop. I wish to see the traces appear one by one for big data drawing which can be slow, so at least c something change as code runs

Any suggestions, not sure where to go from here!

Comment: http://community.plot.ly/t/update-view-after-every-iteration-plotly-js-addtraces-loop/1479/5

Comment: have you tried `$timeout()` ?

Comment: not here, i'll give it a go

Comment: reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Ignored! no error, delay duration no effect, all traces appear at end of loop, but no issue with the counter being out of sync!!?

Comment: Is the original issue that by the time the code in the timeout runs the value of `c` has changed to the next value in the loop?

Comment: @Lex No, the original issue is that the addedTraces arent reflected in the view one by one but all at the end

Comment: @Al Right, but you mentioned an error being thrown because of an "unsynchronized counter 'c'". That's what I was asking about.

Comment: @Lex Yes correct, this is the issue with the attempt of prioritising the trace draw with setTimeout. But that issue disappears with the use $timeout...but the issue persist in the sense that the view is not updated until all traces have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Using a foreach instead of for loop somehow solved the issue,,,

```
$scope.graphPlots2.forEach(function(trace, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        Plotly.newPlot('graphRender', [trace], $scope.layout2);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            Plotly.addTraces('graphRender', trace);
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's more than just a change to a `forEach`; that's completely different code. It seems obvious you left something out of your original question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes you are right, I edited original post to reflect the original error/code